# How to count number of words inside a string using a for loop in python 3

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

I am trying to write a for loop that finds a specific word inside a string. I know that there is a one liner to do this in python, but I am practicing the for loops and I want to see how using a for I can identify specific words as it identifies especific letters (like vowels). I've been reading some questions, and I think the code should go like this:

```
s='bananasdasdnansbanana'
b='banana'
def count_words(s,b):
    answer = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if any(s[i:].startswith(b) for b in s):
           answer += 1
    print(answer)
```

but it is not printing anything. I did something similar when I was looking for vowels in the same string, but now I know I am supouse to "arrange" the characters in the word "banana" and then comparate it to the string, that is the porpuse of this part:

```
if any(s[i:].startswith(b) for b in s):
```

if you could help me I would really apreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Side note: If you are practicing loops why use `any`? `any` is really just a hidden loop.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you.

Comment: Also, format your code correctly (hit the edit button to do so). It is currently not indented correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't print because you don't call the `function(you only define it)`, you should call the function by adding a command at the end:

   ```python
   count_words(s,b)
   ```
2. Your function actually count the number of character in string s:

   ```python
   s='bananasdasdnansbanana'
   b='banana'
   def count_words(s,b):
       answer = 0
       # Loop over each character in s
       for i in range(len(s)):
           # create a list contain at least current character => any will always return True
           if any(s[i:].startswith(b) for b in s):
               answer += 1
       print(answer)
   ```
3. Right codes:

   ```python
   s='bananasdasdnansbanana'
   b='banana'
   def count_words(s,b):
       answer = 0
       for i in range(len(s)):
           if s[i:].startswith(b):
               answer += 1
       print(answer)

   count_words(s,b)
   ```

Comment: I am learning python and your answer not only helped me solve the problem, but also helped understand what I was getting wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s='bananasdasdnansbanana'
b='banana'
def count_words(s,b):
    answer = 0
    counter = 0
    if b in s:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i]!=b[counter]:
                counter=0
            else:
                counter+=1
            if counter == len(b):
                answer+=1
                counter = 0
    print(answer)

count_words(s, b)
```

Above algorithm first check whether banana exists in s at least once. Then, it will loop to find the count.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use a for loop, you could find the length of the word you're looking for, then check sections of the larger string that are the same length and see if they match. You don't need to use `any` unless you are intentionally wanting to. Something like this:

```python
s='bananasdasdnansbanana'
b='banana'
def count_words(s,b):
    word_length = len(b)
    answer = 0
    for i in range(len(s) - len(b) + 1):
        if s[i:i+word_length] == b:
            answer += 1
    return answer

count_words(s,b)
```

Note I also changed your `print` to `return`. It works either way.